# Continuously reading from serial port

Tags: rust, serial-port

I have a LoRa module which is connected to a serial port. I want to send a number of argument to configure it, but the connection times out after the first argument. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```rust
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let port = serialport::new("/dev/ttyS0", 115_200)
        .timeout(Duration::from_millis(6000))
        .open();

    match port {
        Ok(mut port) => {
            let mut serial_buf: Vec<u8> = vec![0; 1000];
            let config = vec![
                "AT+CFG=433500000,5,9,7,1,1,0,0,0,0,3000,8,4\r\n",
                "AT+RX\r\n",
                "AT+SAVE\r\n",
            ];

            for entry in config.iter() {
                port.write(entry.as_bytes()).expect("Write failed!");
                Duration::from_millis(1500);

                loop {
                    match port.read(serial_buf.as_mut_slice()) {
                        Ok(t) => io::stdout().write_all(&serial_buf[..t]).unwrap(),
                        Err(e) => eprintln!("{:?}", e),
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            ::std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

My working Python code:

```py
main.py:
connection = Connection('/dev/ttys013', 115200, 8, 'N', 1, 1)    
configuration.config_module(
'AT+CFG=433500000,5,9,7,1,1,0,0,0,0,3000,8,4', 'AT+RX', 'AT+SAVE')

configuration.py:
def config_module(self, *arguments):
    self.connection.write_to_mcu(arguments[0])
    for i in range(0, 1):        
        time.sleep(2)
        validation = self.connection.read_from_mcu()
        print(validation[:-1].decode())
    for i in range(1, len(arguments)):
        self.connection.write_to_mcu(arguments[i])
        time.sleep(2)       
        validation_from_mcu = self.connection.read_from_mcu()
        print(validation_from_mcu[:-1].decode())

connection.py:
def write_to_mcu(self, message):
    self.serial_connection.write((message + '\r\n').encode())

def read_from_mcu(self):
    return self.serial_connection.readline()
```

Comment: Are you sure the LoRa device (got a link?) is working correctly? e.g. does it come with any test programs? and/or can you read/write from the terminal/shell?

Comment: Also, are you sure `/dev/ttyS0` is the correct path? Modern computers use serial ports over USB and so are usually located at `/dev/ttyUSB0` etc, see https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-10.html

Comment: Yes, it is working correctly. I have a fully working Python application but I need to rewrite it in Rust because of the low level advantages.

Comment: Please post your working Python program.

Comment: I noticed your Python code is using `/dev/ttys013` but your Rust code is using `dev/ttyS0`.

Comment: `Duration::from_millis(1500);` doesn't do anything useful. If you want the thread to sleep then use `std::thread:sleep` - but ideally you should never sleep a thread and instead you should be using async IO and an asynchronous delay function, like `tokio::time::sleep` or `async_std::task::sleep`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong line the `/dev/ttys013` is my socat test environment. I gonna look into the `tokio` crate

Answer (score 0):

You probably already found the bug, but i'll try to answer the question anyway. The main issue was your infinite loop.

```
use std::io::{self, Write, BufRead, BufReader};
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut port = serialport::new("/dev/ttyS0", 115_200)
        .timeout(Duration::from_millis(6000))
        .open()
        // expect does exactly the same thing as your match did
        .expect("Error: ");

    // in your python you use readline, to archive this
    // in rust the easiest way is to use a BufReader
    let mut port = BufReader::new(port);
    let mut line_buffer = String::new();
    let config = vec![
        "AT+CFG=433500000,5,9,7,1,1,0,0,0,0,3000,8,4\r\n",
        "AT+RX\r\n",
        "AT+SAVE\r\n",
    ];

    for entry in config.iter() {
        // get_mut is required because BufReader does not implement
        // io::Write
        port.get_mut()
            // use write_all because write does not guarantee that
            // every byte gets written
            .write_all(entry.as_bytes()).expect("Write failed!");

        // Duration::from_millis only returns a Duration and does not sleep
        std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1500));

        // clear the line buffer to use it again
        line_buffer.clear();
        // previously you never stopped reading
        port.read_line(&mut line_buffer).expect("Read failed!");

        // maybe you have a reason to use io::stdout().write_all()
        // but most times you can just use println or print
        print!("{}", line_buffer);
    }
}
```

**Docs**

- [Write::write](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write)
- [BufRead::read_line](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line)
- [Duration::from_millis](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Duration.html#method.from_millis)
- [std::thread::sleep](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html)